# Gill Sans - possible to use on Linux with pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, sans-serif

There are numerous old posts whose topic relates to using the font Gill Sans in LaTeX documents. The most notable are perhaps [this post from 2007](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/M6ZhPm5VhmY) and [this one from 2010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/recommendations-for-substitution-of-non-free-fonts-with-latex-typefaces). The former gives a solution for XeLaTeX, which I don't particularly feel inclined to convert to, and the latter gives a solution which involves using otfinst to package OpenType fonts from the Arkandis Digital Foundry (ADF), a more attractive solution.

However, I note that -- in Britain, at least -- the font was released into the public domain in 2011. I was wondering, therefore, if a package now existed for it so I could use it in standard LaTeX documents. If not, what is the best way for me to go about creating such a package, so that both myself and others can use it?.

Comment: It's only the design of Gill Sans that is now public domain; the actual font files produced by Monotype (and other type foundries) are still their intellectual property. If you want to provide pdfLaTeX support for Gill Sans, I suggest you look at the documentation for the [New Font Selection Scheme](http://latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) as well as the style file for the Latin Modern fonts, since they are also in OpenType format.

Comment: See https://ctan.org/pkg/gillius for a clone of Gill Sans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something like a package which makes it possible to use a similar font with latex/pdflatex. See here:

http://www.gaehrken.de/tex/bgillsans.txt

This uses the Font Humanist521 wich is similar to Gill Sans. You can find Humanist521 on old CorelDraw CDs.

Comment: Just be careful about font licensing. As far as I understand http://www.corel.com/corel/pages/index.jsp?pgid=800340, you would need to add _"Copyright (c) 201___ _[Your name], Corel Corporation and its licensors. All rights reserved."_ to you work to comply with the license if you use Humanist521 or any other font from the Corel CD...